# Python BeautifulSoup, extract text based on two tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am mining text by using the BeautifulSoup:

This is part of the HTML

```
[<dl class="py method">
 <dt class="sig sig-object py" id="sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply">
 <span class="sig-name descname"><span class="pre">apply</span></span><span class="sig-paren">(</span><em class="sig-param"><span class="n"><span class="pre">X</span></span></em>, <em class="sig-param"><span class="n"><span class="pre">check_input</span></span><span class="o"><span class="pre">=</span></span><span class="default_value"><span class="pre">True</span></span></em><span class="sig-paren">)</span><a class="reference external" href="https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca1/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L494"><span class="viewcode-link"><span class="pre">[source]</span></span></a><a class="headerlink" href="#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply" title="Permalink to this definition">¶</a></dt>
 <dd><p>Return the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as.</p>
 <div class="versionadded">
 <p><span class="versionmodified added">New in version 0.17.</span></p>
 </div>
 <dl class="field-list simple">
 <dt class="field-odd">Parameters</dt>
 <dd class="field-odd"><dl class="simple">
 <dt><strong>X</strong><span class="classifier">{array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)</span></dt><dd><p>The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
 <code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">dtype=np.float32</span></code> and if a sparse matrix is provided
 to a sparse <code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">csr_matrix</span></code>.</p>
 </dd>
 <dt><strong>check_input</strong><span class="classifier">bool, default=True</span></dt><dd><p>Allow to bypass several input checking.
 Don’t use this parameter unless you know what you do.</p>
 </dd>
 </dl>
 </dd>
 <dt class="field-even">Returns</dt>
 <dd class="field-even"><dl class="simple">
 <dt><strong>X_leaves</strong><span class="classifier">array-like of shape (n_samples,)</span></dt><dd><p>For each datapoint x in X, return the index of the leaf x
 ends up in. Leaves are numbered within
 <code class="docutils literal notranslate"><span class="pre">[0;</span> <span class="pre">self.tree_.node_count)</span></code>, possibly with gaps in the
 numbering.</p>
 </dd>
 </dl>
 </dd>
 </dl>
```

But I only want the "Return the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as."

I think we could use `<dd> && <p>` to extract this sentence, but I tried many ways, still have not figured it out.

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: what is your question? which "two tags" do you mean?  if you know in advance the string you can use a regex, `soup.find(string=re.compile("Return..."))`

Answer (score 2):

You can apply css selector as follows:

```
html = '''
<html>
 <body>
  <dl class="py method">
   <dt class="sig sig-object py" id="sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply">
    <span class="sig-name descname">
     <span class="pre">
      apply
     </span>
    </span>
    <span class="sig-paren">
     (
    </span>
    <em class="sig-param">
     <span class="n">
      <span class="pre">
       X
      </span>
     </span>
    </em>
    ,
    <em class="sig-param">
     <span class="n">
      <span class="pre">
       check_input
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="o">
      <span class="pre">
       =
      </span>
     </span>
     <span class="default_value">
      <span class="pre">
       True
      </span>
     </span>
    </em>
    <span class="sig-paren">
     )
    </span>
    <a class="reference external" href="https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/baf828ca1/sklearn/tree/_classes.py#L494">
     <span class="viewcode-link">
      <span class="pre">
       [source]
      </span>
     </span>
    </a>
    <a class="headerlink" href="#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.apply" title="Permalink to this definition">
     ¶
    </a>
   </dt>
   <dd>
    <p>
     Return the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as.
    </p>
    <div class="versionadded">
     <p>
      <span class="versionmodified added">
       New in version 0.17.
      </span>
     </p>
    </div>
    <dl class="field-list simple">
     <dt class="field-odd">
      Parameters
     </dt>
     <dd class="field-odd">
      <dl class="simple">
       <dt>
        <strong>
         X
        </strong>
        <span class="classifier">
         {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
        </span>
       </dt>
       <dd>
        <p>
         The input samples. Internally, it will be converted to
         <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
          <span class="pre">
           dtype=np.float32
          </span>
         </code>
         and if a sparse matrix is provided
 to a sparse
         <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
          <span class="pre">
           csr_matrix
          </span>
         </code>
         .
        </p>
       </dd>
       <dt>
        <strong>
         check_input
        </strong>
        <span class="classifier">
         bool, default=True
        </span>
       </dt>
       <dd>
        <p>
         Allow to bypass several input checking.
 Don’t use this parameter unless you know what you do.
        </p>
       </dd>
      </dl>
     </dd>
     <dt class="field-even">
      Returns
     </dt>
     <dd class="field-even">
      <dl class="simple">
       <dt>
        <strong>
         X_leaves
        </strong>
        <span class="classifier">
         array-like of shape (n_samples,)
        </span>
       </dt>
       <dd>
        <p>
         For each datapoint x in X, return the index of the leaf x
 ends up in. Leaves are numbered within
         <code class="docutils literal notranslate">
          <span class="pre">
           [0;
          </span>
          <span class="pre">
           self.tree_.node_count)
          </span>
         </code>
         , possibly with gaps in the
 numbering.
        </p>
       </dd>
      </dl>
     </dd>
    </dl>
   </dd>
  </dl>
 </body>
</html>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
#print(soup.prettify())

txt=soup.select_one('.py.method > dt + dd p').find(text=True)
print(txt)
```

**Output:**

```
 Return the index of the leaf that each sample is predicted as.
```